# nested exception is com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:

Tags: java, ibatis

I am new to `Java`, I am trying to call a stored procedure from `Java`.

I am getting this exception for this code

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Object> queryForList(String procName, Map<String, Object> map, CommonVO commonVO) {
    List<Object> resultSetList = null;
    Date connectionAttemptStartDate = null;
    Date cidbQueryStartDate = null;
    List<String> jndiNameList =null;
    String jndiName = null;
    try {
        resultSetList = super.queryForList(procName, map);

    }catch(Exception e) {
        isError = true;
        //exception = e;
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        exception=ExceptionUtils.validateCreateCIDBException(e);
    }
    return resultSetList;
 }
```

My `XML` file here

```
<!DOCTYPE sqlMap PUBLIC "-//iBATIS.com//DTD SQL Map 2.0//EN" "http://www.ibatis.com/dtd/sql-map-2.dtd">
<sqlMap namespace="SP">
    <parameterMap id="objectParameters" class="java.util.Map">      
        <parameter property="valueAddedOfferList" jdbcType="VALUE_ADDED_OFFER_LIST" typeName="VALUE_ADDED_OFFER_LIST" typeHandler="com.bam.vision.dao.db.typehandler.ValueAddedOfferListTypeHandlerCallback" mode="OUT" />
        <parameter property="errorCode" jdbcType="INTEGER" javaType="java.lang.String" mode="OUT"/>
        <parameter property="errorMessage" jdbcType="CHAR" javaType="java.lang.String" mode="OUT"/>
    </parameterMap>
    <procedure id="retrieve_value_added_offer" parameterMap="objectParameters" timeout="2">
        {call retrieve_value_added_offer(?,?,?)}
    </procedure>
</sqlMap>
```

Getting exception like here

```
--- Cause: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal    incompatible with java.lang.String; nested exception is     com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:   
--- The error occurred in retrieve_value_added_offer.xml.  
--- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.  
--- Check the SP.objectParameters.  
--- Check the output parameters (retrieval of output parameters failed).  
--- Cause: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal incompatible with java.lang.String
```

Answer (score 0):

This line in your XML file looks suspicious to me:

```
    <parameter property="errorCode" jdbcType="INTEGER" javaType="java.lang.String" mode="OUT"/>
```

What type is the `errorCode` code parameter in your stored procedure?

You have `jdbcType="INTEGER"`, which suggests it's a number, but you also have `javaType="java.lang.String"`, which suggests it's a string.  Clearly it can't be both.  You haven't included the declaration of your stored procedure so it's impossible to tell which one it actually is.

If your error code is an integer, try changing `javaType="java.lang.String"` to `javaType="java.lang.Integer"` (or if that fails, `javaType="java.math.BigDecimal"` instead).  If your error code is a string, change `jdbcType="INTEGER"` to `jdbcType="STRING"`.